# Why is BK 1:2 in first person?

Tags: bava-kamma

*Bava Kama*, chapter 1, *mishna* 2:

> כל שחבתי בשמירתו הכשרתי את נזקו הכשרתי במקצת נזקו חבתי בתשלומין כהכשר כל נזקו
>
> Whatever I'm responsible to watch, I'm [deemed to have] prepared its damage. If I prepared some of its damage, I became responsible for payments like preparing all its damage.

I'm no *mishnayos* expert, but am unfamiliar with any other case where the rules are written in the first person. Certainly it's unusual. Why is this *mishna* written that way?

Comment: Rabbi Shimon in Sheviis 2:3

Comment: Does Avos 1:14 count?

Comment: Also Abba Shaul in Shabbos 23:3

Answer (score 4):

This question was raised by [R. Menachem Azaria of Fano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menahem_Azariah_da_Fano) in [Asarah Ma'amarot, Ma'amar Chikur Hadin 5:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42338&st=&pgnum=89)

> וכמה הוא מן המתמיהין התנא הזה לתלות בעצמו קללת אחרים
>
> How astounding it is that this *tanna* hung the curse of others on himself!

I'm not sure I quite understand his answer, but it sounds like he is saying that this *tanna* is (metaphorically?) God, in accordance with the Talmud's assertion on 6b that the *tanna* of this Mishnah is a Jerusalemite who employs לישנא דקלילא, which R. Menachem apparently interprets as being an expression of leniency rather than stringency. Thus, God seems to be saying that He applied the rule of "paying from the best of the land" to destroy the Holy Temple rather than destroying the people:

> אלא ודאי מאן תנא דא קב"ה שרצה לזכות את ישראל והוא תנא ירושלמי דתני לישנא קלילא כדאיתא בגמרא אסיפא דרישא דקתני חב המזיק ומשמעו להקל ולא להחמיר וכך אמר להם בני אל תרגזו ממה ששניתי לכם חב המזיק לשלם תשלומי נזק כי אמנם לא אמרתי אלא במיטב הארץ והכוונה לשפוך את החימה על העצים ועל האבנים וכטעם וכפר אדמתו עמו לפי פשוטו ולנו פשט ותר נגלה ומוכרח ממנו דהוה ליה למימר וכפרה אדמתו עמו או וכפר באדמתו עמו אלא הכי קאמר וכפר עמו על אדמתו של מעלה בתשובה ומעשים טובים כמו שפירשנו בחלק הראשון פסוק וכפר על הקדש בפרק י"ג וזה וזה כפתור ופרח ואפילו תימא דמיטב הארץ על גוף האדם אתמר שהוא ודאי חלתו של עולם מכל מקום יש תקוה לאחריתו ונפשו בטוב תלין כי אנכי אנכי הוא מוחה פשעיך למעני אשר הרעותי לתת שאור בעסה כמו שדרשו במסכת סוכה ועם זה חבתי בשמירתו הכשרתי את נזקו כי צר לב האדם רע מנעוריו כדאיתא התם ומעקרא נמי הכשרתי במקצת נזקו שמעטתי את הירח חבתי בתשלומי נזקו כהכשר כל נזקו כטעם ושעיר עזים אחד לחטאת לה' לפיכך לא יהיה לך עוד השמש לאור יומם ולנגה הירח לא יאיר לך כי ה' יהיה לך לאור עולם רבנן מתנו בור של שני שותפין השני חייב כי אמנם נחנו פשענו ומרינו והוא ודוי מעליא לעורר רחמי המקום אמר הקב"ה בני לא כך היא המדה אלא כסהו השני כראוי אלו תקנות חכמים העושים סייג לתורה ונפל שמה שור או חמור ומת פטור כי הא דאמור רבנן שור ולא אדם מבעלי איקונין ראשונה שבארנו במאמר הנפש כי יפול הנופל ממחוסרי התולדות שהם בהמה המה להם חמור ולא כלים שלא זכו לדיקונין קדושים הנזכרים שם שהן באמת איקונין שניה אלמא לאו בני מזלא נינהו האובדים האלה לפיכך השני פטור ואני הוא שמעטתי להם את התולדות במשפטי ה' אמת צדקו יחדו ואני עתיד להשלימם להם כמו שנבאר בפרקים הללו. וכבר דרשו בפרק חלק לי גלעד לי מנשה על חבתן של פושעי ישראל לפני המקום אחרי הוכבס את הנגע מבגדיהם והטהרו ואיתא נמי בברייתא דרבי אליעזר פרק י"ז

Answer (score 3):

**[Kollel Iyun Hadaf](https://www.dafyomi.co.il/)** suggested 2 interesting answers to this question:

> 1) "**Kol ha'ReMeZ**"-- a commentary on the Mishnah by [Rav Moshe Zacuto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ben_Mordecai_Zacuto) (1625-1697)-- explains our Mishnah based on the Mishnah below ([Bava Kamma 26a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.26a.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) that says "Adam Mu'ad l'Olam." A person is always liable for any damage he does, whether it happened deliberately or accidentally. This is because, when it comes to damages, everyone is like a "Chaver," a Talmid Chacham, who does not require a warning to make him liable (see [Makkos 6b](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.6b.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)). Our Mishnah speaks in the first person to hint that everyone is equal when it comes to his responsibility to guard his property.
>
> 2) The **Sefer "Ahavah b'Ta'anugim**" by [Rav Avraham Azulai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Azulai) (1570-1643) the great-grandfather of the Chida, writes that our Mishnah is written in the first person to teach that the laws of damages are logical ones. They do not belong in the category of "Chukim," the laws of the Torah whose reasons we do not always understand. They are "Mishpatim." Everyone agrees that he has to make himself obligated for any damage he does. Even if we did not possess the Torah, a person's "*seichel*" would be sufficient to know that he has to pay for the results of his actions. The Mishnah is written in the first person because every individual would admit that "I am liable for what I did."